# Interactively Interrupt or Abort a Running Computation in Mathematica Online Without Losing Kernel

Tags: mathematica-online

How can I interactively interrupt or abort a running calculation in Mathematica Online without killing the kernel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least as of August 3, 2018, the evaluate menu now has an abort option.